# Matching regex lookarounds in Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm trying to do a pretty big search and replace across a number of files. I need to prefix certain part of a file with a forward slash, so here's my search regexp:

```
(?<=source=['"])(?=\.\./assets)
```

and here's my replacement string:

```
/
```

Here's my query:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/embed/graphics/logo.png")]
```

The output of this should look like this:

```
[Embed(source="/../assets/embed/graphics/logo.png")]
```

However, unfortunately, `matches()` returns false, though `find()` returns true, and Eclipse doesn't find files/lines which can be modified. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? How can I get it to match, yet keep my expression simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to use lookarounds, so you're making it harder on yourself. "Keep it simple" is my philosophy, so here's what I would do:

```
myString.replaceAll('source=(["\'])\.\./assets', 'source=$1/../assets')
```

Comment: but lookarounds are _soooooo_ hacker!